# CSS - When resizing browser, columns overlap (right hand size and center column)

Tags: html, css, css-float

So I have 3 columns, left side (text), middle (image), right side (text). When I resize the browser, the right side column and center column overlap slightly, but not completely. The right side column goes underneath the image (center column)

## CSS

```
.column-container {
padding-top: 3%;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
width: 99%; }

.left-column {
padding-top: 0%;
float: left;
width: 33%;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;  }

.right-column {
padding-top: 0%;
float: right;
width: 33%;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: left;
display: inline-block;

.center-column {
display: inline-block;
width: 33%; }
```

### What happens when making browser small: (not enough rep to post images)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCSDd.jpg

I've been messing around with it for quite some time now. Help would be much appreciated.

### Edit: HTML Code

```
 <div class="column-container">
    <div class="left-column">
        <h4> North </h4>
        <p>The app uses an  interactive map to represent the surrounding area, where locations can be found. <br/><br/><br/>

        Users can sign up to receive their own unique login details in order to create a team and start playing. <br/><br/><br/>

        Users can take pictures to verify the different locations of a hunt. <br/><br/><br/>

        The app has integrated social media platforms. Share your journey with friends and family! <br/><br/><br/>

        Users will be presented with clues that they can use to complete treasure hunts.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="center-column">
        <div class="imgContainer3"><img src="pictures/SamsungPhone2.png" alt="App"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="right-column">
        <h4> North West </h4>
        <p class="g">The portal allows administrators to choose locations and create clues to form treasure hunts. <br/><br/><br/>

        The portal is secure, with each administrator having their own unique login details. <br/><br/><br/>

        The portal receives data from the app that can be analysed by admins. <br/><br/><br/>

        The portal allows administrators to verify photos that have been sent from teams on a trasure hunt. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML code?

Comment: Sure! Gimme a sec.

Comment: Maybe you could add `style="width: 100%"` to the img element. The problem is, that the image has no size and is using the original size of the image. Furthermore in your CSS code above the `}`is missing after the `.right-column` block.

Comment: You've half fixed it, but now the image is squished/distorted.

Comment: The image should be adjusted automatically. Because only the width is specified the height get's calculated automatically. Maybe you could send a new screen shot?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/af569f5e843595fc643d12b2b550e63b and when full screen: https://gyazo.com/9973fee9015a611bb7e26f273b3af93b

Comment: Do you have also specified a height somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, there's a height specified for the "content block" that this section resides in.

Comment: Maybe this could cause your problem. Could you post this part of your code?